# IE7 not making JSON request for FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar with a JSON feed and as per usual it works fine in Firefox/Chrome/Safari but IE7 is not playing ball. It's not throwing any errors, it's simply not making the request to the events feed at all (using DebugBar I can see it's not making the callout and back-end logs confirm this).

Anybody else encountered this problem? It shouldn't be a caching issue as fullCalendar now includes a cachebuster on the request.

Cheers,

Matt

Comment: Have you done any tracing or debugging through the code?

Comment: Does it work on IE8 or IE9? I assume you're using jQuery's FullCalendar plugin.  Are you getting the request on the server?

Comment: No it wasn't getting the request at all, after posting this I had to re-factor a lot of the solution anyway and at some stage it apparently started making the request again. Unfortunately I never got to the bottom of the problem so can't suggest anything for others to try, but if it does crop up again I'll be sure to post any findings here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea without looking at your code, but I'm willing to guess that you might have had an extra trailing comma or a missing semi-colon somewhere in your code.  IE7's JavaScript interpreter will take a big poop on you if you have even the slightest of syntactical mistakes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was all good, but there could easily have been a syntax error hidden away somewhere, quite a large chunk of the javascript on the page was programmatically generated so that could explain the sudden fix.